# Figure out which CRC16 algorithm was used

Tags: crc16

I have a serial communication protocol and having some trouble finding out about checksum algorithm that has been used. I've tried several `CRC16 algorithms` and none of them seem to work.

messages looks like this ( in Hex ):

```
55 13 04 03 09 f1 01 00 00 06 50 08 00 02 00 00 00 cc 1a 
55 13 04 03 09 f1 01 00 00 06 50 00 00 02 00 00 00 94 3b
55 13 04 03 09 f1 02 00 00 06 50 08 00 02 00 00 00 7f e4 
55 13 04 03 09 f1 02 00 00 06 50 00 00 02 00 00 00 27 c5
55 13 04 03 09 f1 03 00 00 06 50 08 00 02 00 00 00 ee b1
55 13 04 03 09 f1 03 00 00 06 50 00 00 02 00 00 00 b6 90
```

I know that the start byte is `0x55` and the 2nd byte is the message length

If necessary, I can provide more data. Any help or hint would be appreciated ;)

Best regards, Amir

Comment: Would this be a good question for [security.SE]?

Answer (score 2):

[this](https://crccalc.com/) CRC calculator is gonna help you.

Comment: This was a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what bytes the CRC is calculated over.

You can use [RevEng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) to try to extract the CRC parameters from examples. From your examples, it is clear that this is a 16-bit CRC with the polynomial `0x1021`, and that the CRC is reflected (the polynomial is bit-reversed when applied to the input, and the CRC register is shifted right, not left). However the initial value and the final exclusive-or depends on what bytes the CRC is calculated over. To really nail those down, you would also need example messages of different lengths.

The [RevEng catalog of 16-bit CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm) has several standard CRCs that it could be:

```
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xffff refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0x6f91 name="CRC-16/MCRF4XX"
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xb2aa refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0x63d0 name="CRC-16/RIELLO"
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0x89ec refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0x26b1 name="CRC-16/TMS37157"
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xc6c6 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0xbf05 name="CRC-A"
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0x0000 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0000 check=0x2189 name="KERMIT"
width=16 poly=0x1021 init=0xffff refin=true refout=true xorout=0xffff check=0x906e name="X-25"
```

I don't get any of those assuming the whole thing is the message, nor if I drop the first one or two bytes.

The most common CRCs from that list are KERMIT (also known as the CCITT CRC-16) and X-25.